# Java soap Web service that can accept different inputs xml and Marshalled accordingly,

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, cxf, spring-ws

Idea is to develop the soap over http web service which is required to accept the multiple xml input form different system . then on arrival of request the raw xml is retrieved and saved and then its marshaled accordingly into appropriate pojo . to make it more flexible pojo could be generated at runtime.

As for the solution , fristly Apache CXF jax-ws was considered but it needed either the contract (wsdl) or java , which we dont have in our case . 
then the CXF provider services (Jaxp) method is considered but Source is difficult parse and dont give the raw xml. using SAX source will generate error in maven java2ws step . and stream source is also giving error on return message. 
Java API for XML messaging is also suggested  method over internet but dint find examples for it
so finally i have no good solution .

secondly ever implementation need the pojo/ schema  beforehand in order to be accepted , is there no dynamic way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a real dynamic way to do this. It's hard to understand your question without any examples or things you've tried yourself.

The whole thing with soap/xsd/wsdl is that all the possible messages are defined in the schema (contract first). That way both parties (client and server) use the same contract and should be able to be developed separately.

The only option you have (and I've seen this numerous times) is to create a service with a (string) field that contains encoded XML. You can provide any type of XML and still be able to validate the whole message using the xsd and wsdl.

I don't really like the solution, but I think this is the only way to get something dynamic.